# Linq to SQL - Many to Many Predicates

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many

I'm familiar with doing simple Many-to-Many relationships (i.e. simple joins) in Linq to SQL, but I'm having a hard time thinking right now.

I have three tables (and so, entities in my Linq-to-SQL model) representing a taxonomic system. Standard-issue really:

Products - ProductTags - Tags

I'm writing a method that returns a set of Products where the Tag they're in matches a query. So if someone searches for "foo" then all products assigned with the tags "foobar" or "fooqux" (but not "bazbar") would be returned.

I know I have to structure the query into two parts: first to get the matching Tags, and then to get the Products that have those tags. It's the second part I'm stumped on.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
var tags = from t in db.Tags
           where t.Name.Contains( tagSearchQuery )
           select t;

var products = from p in db.Products
               // then a miracle happens
               select p;
```

Assistance much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it in one query if you just start with the `ProductTags` table. You'll probably  also need a `Distinct` to avoid duplicate products matching multiple tags.

```
var products = (from pt in db.ProductTags
                where pt.Tag.Name.Contains( tagSearchQuery )
                select pt.Product).Distinct();
```

or here's another way:

```
var products = from p in db.Products
                  from pt in p.ProductTags
                  where pt.Tag.Name.Contains( tagSearchQuery )
                  select p
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IQueryable<Tag> tags =
  from t in db.Tags
  where t.Name.Contains( tagSearchQuery )
  select t;

IQueryable<Product> products =
  from p in db.Products
  where p.ProductTags.Any(pt => tags.Contains(pt.Tag))
  select p;
```

OR

```
IQueryable<Product> products =
  from p in db.Products
  from pt in p.ProductTags
  let t = pt.Tag
  where t.Name.Contains( tagSearchFragment )
  group t by p into g
  select g.Key;
```